# Mapkit to show results formatted like so: city, state, country

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit

I have been developing an application and I am new to the whole Mapkit idea. I am wanting my app to allow a user to search for a location but only display results like city, state, country and not address or points of interest. I know this may be a simple question but I am having a hard time finding the answer. Just for example if a user typed "San" into my searchbar, it would pull up "San Antonio, Tx, United States" and every other location that has San in it. I'm sure there is a way to implement this without having to create a giant database or json tree. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [MKLocalSearchRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalsearchrequest), thats basic MapKit searching.